# Get raw SQL query for further execution in database client

Tags: django, django-mssql

How am I able to retrieve the produced plain SQL statement from a Django ORM query which I can use in another database client program?

For example, having a `ModelA.objects.filter(name='abc')` queryset. I imagine setting a breakpoint somewhere in the Django/3rd-party-apps code to get a plain `Select * from TabelModelA where name='abc';` statement which I can directly copy/paste into DBeaver or something else and execute without the need for further processing into the needed SQL dialect.

We use Server SQL and the django-mssql package.

I know the django.db.connection.queries thing and its resulting SQL/params strings, but that's not what I mean. Is there something else? Or is it doable in pyodbc? Or is there another technique?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you want to do.

But for getting SQL queries made by Django ORM, these two projects are quite usefull :

https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar

https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk

or natively :

```py
qs = ModelA.objects.filter(name='abc')
print(qs.query)
```

Comment: I have to try django-silk, but the debug-toolbar and qs.query is what I meant by the last part of my question. This is not the solution.
I want the query directly in MSSQL dialect

Comment: when I read your question again, I understand that my response was totally appropriated.

Comment: the django-silk hint was helpful but I still have to modify the sql query to use it in dbeaver.